# Upper bound of $(1-1/a)^{b-1}$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, integers

I have seen in a proof that for $a,b$ positive integers and for $b\geq a+1$ it is true that
$$(1-1/a)^{b-1}\leq e^{-1}$$
but this is not clear to me by the exponential series and the obvious upper bound is $1$.

Comment: Basically it's because $(1-1/n)^n$ approaches $1/e$ from below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Here is one way - note $e^x$ is convex and hence stays above its tangent at $x=0$, so $e^x \ge 1+x$. Now set $x =-\frac1a$ and simplify.